# Shape mismatch when using fsolve in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
#solve for U[i],sig[i]

def f(x):
    u=x[0]
    v=x[1]
    s1=0 #sum
    s2=0
    for j in range (N-i,N+i+1):
        s1=s1+Qu[j,i]/(1+u*exp(v*(N-j)*sdt)*dt)
        s2=s2+Qd[j,i]/(1+u*exp(v*(N-j)*sdt)*dt)

    return [Pu[i+1]-s1,Pd[i+1]-s2]

result=fsolve(f,[0,0])
```

> TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'f'.Shape should be (2,) but it is (2, 1).

All other parameters are known numbers (except u,v).

The following is a success example and I think that my code has the same format.

```
# success example

def f(x):                                  
    u=x[0]
    v=x[1]
    return [u+v-4, u**2+v**2-8]   

result=fsolve(f,[0,0])
```

They have the same format, but the first one did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit `f(x)` so that it returns an array of shape (2,) or a 2 element list (not a nested list).  Review the difference between shape (2,) and (2,1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can you tell the difference between the two code. Why the second one works?

Answer (score 0):

With your second `f`:

```
In [596]: def f(x):                                  
     ...:     u=x[0]
     ...:     v=x[1]
     ...:     return [u+v-4, u**2+v**2-8]   
     ...:
```

I give it a 2 element list, and get back a 2 element list

```
In [597]: f([0,0])
Out[597]: [-4, -8]
```

Actually `fsolve` will turn your `x0` into a 2 element array, and treat the return as an array as well

```
In [598]: f(np.array([0,0]))
Out[598]: [-4, -8]

In [599]: np.array(f(np.array([0,0])))
Out[599]: array([-4, -8])
In [600]: _.shape
Out[600]: (2,)
```

I can't demonstrate your first `f` because of all the undefined variables (Qu, Pu, etc).  I suppose I could guess reasonable shapes, but I don't like to do that.

But the error message indicates that it generates something like:

```
In [601]: np.array([[1],[2]])
Out[601]: 
array([[1],
       [2]])
In [602]: _.shape
Out[602]: (2, 1)
```

I could imitate that with a little change to your 2nd `f`:

```
In [606]: def f1(x):                                  
     ...:     u=x[0]
     ...:     v=x[1]
     ...:     return [[u+v-4], [u**2+v**2-8]]   
     ...: 
In [607]: optimize.fsolve(f1,[0,0])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-607-a21691ae31f8> in <module>()
----> 1 optimize.fsolve(f1,[0,0])

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in fsolve(func, x0, args, fprime, full_output, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    144                'diag': diag}
    145 
--> 146     res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
    147     if full_output:
    148         x = res['x']

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, eps, factor, diag, **unknown_options)
    210     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    211         args = (args,)
--> 212     shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
    213     if epsfcn is None:
    214         epsfcn = finfo(dtype).eps

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     38                 msg += "."
     39             msg += 'Shape should be %s but it is %s.' % (output_shape, shape(res))
---> 40             raise TypeError(msg)
     41     if issubdtype(res.dtype, inexact):
     42         dt = res.dtype

TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'f1'.Shape should be (2,) but it is (2, 1).
```

So it's performs a test calculation, something like `f(x0)`, and checks the dimensions of what is returned. And complains when they don't match its expectations.

Remember in `numpy` arrays can have 0, 1, 2 or more dimensions.  In contrast MATLAB has a minimum of 2d.  So in numpy a shape like (2,) is different from (2,1) or (1,2).  They all have 2 elements, and may be reshaped to each other, but for many operations the number of dimensions matters.

`[1,2]`, `[[1],[2]]` and `[[1,2]]` are the equivalent list expressions.